# Setter not getting called when using DoubleUpDown from the extended WPF toolkit

Tags: wpf, xaml

Has anyone used this control? Is there something I am missing? I created a WPF interface to tune a PID controller (just a line follower built from NXT) and I am trying to adjust my constants using the DoubleUpDown control, I can bind to the properties in my service no problem and see them so the getter is getting called but when I change values I never see the setter fire off (i.e. breakpoint never gets hit).

Any advice would be great!

Thanks...

Here is some code to go with this, this is just a normal dependency property - in this case value is getting assigned to a double that is part of the service (my datacontext) but that isn't any different from when I use an adapter at work on some boring business form - Lego's are way cooler...

```
public double Kp
    {
        get { return service.kp; }
        set
        {
            service.kp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Kp");
        }
    }
```

Even if there was a problem there (setting the field in the service) I should at least be able to put a break point at `service.kp = value` and see it trying to set it, and yeah - I will post this over at the wpf extended toolkit forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your constants are actual public dependency properties, or public properties on a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  You should post this in the Discussions on the Extended WPF Toolkit project site.  Also check your output window for any binding errors.  Can you provide some code?

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

UPDATED:

Based on the code you provided in the Discussions section of rthe project site; you should bind the property to the Value proeprty of the DoubleUpDown control and not the Text.

Comment: Hi - that's I will look into that... I went out of town and found out the hotel didn't have free internet (err) and there was just no time to check this anywhere else. I will update tonight and mark the answer.